# Partial differentiation for parallel Resistance Problem

Tags: calculus, physics

I have this solved problem , and is not clear for me how the teacher got the result.
I tried doing someting on the right side of the picture, but i am not sure is correct ...
I wonder if someone can show me step by step

[image: My test]

Comment: I think the easier way to proceed would be to start with the equation for $\frac{1}{R_T}$ and differentiate implicitly: $-\frac{\frac{\partial R_T}{\partial R_1}}{R_T^2}=-\frac{1}{R_1^2}$, so $\frac{\partial R_T}{\partial R_1}=\frac{R_T^2}{R_1^2}$.

Comment: ...I see now that this is what your teacher did, actually. Anyway, I think you made some chain rule errors in places. For instance when you differentiate $\frac{1}{R_T}$ you need to first differentiate the power before differentiating $R_T$ itself.

Comment: I look at this problem and ask why you don't just set $R_2=22$ and $R_3=3.8$ and recompute to see what the change is. The usefulness of partial derivatives here is much greater when we want a general formula that will solve _many_ problems like this quickly, especially if the variations in the individual resistances are much smaller. (For larger variations the method becomes inaccurate due to nonlinearity.) I think the problem would be better with fewer specific numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$R_T^{-1}=R_1^{-1}+R_2^{-1}+R_3^{-1}.$$

Take the partial derivative on $R_1$ and get

$$-R_T^{-2}\frac{\partial R_T}{\partial R_1}=-R_1^{-2}$$ or

$$\frac{\partial R_T}{\partial R_1}=\frac{R_T^2}{R_1^2}$$ and similarly for the other resistances.

Then

$$\Delta R_T\approx \frac{R_T^2}{R_1^2}\Delta R_1+\frac{R_T^2}{R_2^2}\Delta R_2+\frac{R_T^2}{R_3^2}\Delta R_3.$$